# capture childs stdio/stderr

Tags: linux, stdout, capture

I am trying to capture a childs stdio/stderr after forking (Linux).
I have played around with sys_pipe and sys_dup2 with no luck. Most references I have sourced refer to work to be done by the child but as I have no control over the child I am not sure what I must do.

From what I understand so far, I need to open a pipe and duplicate the handle before forking. The parent then tries to read the pipe but it is not returning anything...The code as such is..

```
    mov rax,22                      ; open a pipe 
    mov rdi,h_Pipe
    syscall

    mov rax,33
    mov rdi,1                       ; duplicate stdout to pipe write
    mov esi,dword[h_Pipe+4]
    syscall

    mov rax,33                      ; duplicate stderr to pipe write
    mov rdi,2
    mov esi,dword[h_Pipe+4]
    syscall
```

........fork...
........wait for child to complete

```
    mov rax,0                       ; Read the pipe
    mov edi,dword[h_Pipe]
    mov rsi,w_Buffer 
    mov rdx,256
    syscall
```

Can anyone assist ??

To calify.....

```
        mov rax,57                   ; fork                                             
        syscall         
        mov [CHILD_PID],rax

.child: cmp qword[CHILD_PID],0                  
        je _CHILD

    mov rax,3                       ; Close
    mov edi,dword[pipe_write]
    syscall

    mov r15d,dword[pipe_read]
    jmp _RUN_EXIT
```

_CHILD:
        mov rax,3                       ; Close
        mov edi,dword[pipe_read]
        syscall

```
    mov rax,33
    mov rdi,1                       ; duplicate stdout to pipe write
    mov esi,dword[pipe_write]
    syscall

    mov rax,33                      ; duplicate stderr to pipe write
    mov rdi,2
    mov esi,dword[pipe_write]
    syscall

    sys_execve
```

subsequent reads on the pipe_read file descriptor returns nothing.

Comment: You have control of the child right up until you invoke `exec*()`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I had RSI and RDI mixed up in the SYS_DUP2 call.
Everything seems to work well now.
Cheers